# Spaces in WHERE clause for SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to find out the records in which a certain column contains exactly one space and nothing else. So I wrote the first of the following queries:

```
select COUNT(*)
from mytable
where col = ' ' -- One space

select COUNT(*)
from mytable
where col = '  ' -- Two spaces

select COUNT(*)
from mytable
where col = '  ' -- Three spaces
```

However, all three queries return the exact same records. Does Microsoft SQL Server not distinguish between the amount of spaces? How can I query exactly for one, two or more spaces?

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/10510/behavior-of-varchar-with-spaces-at-the-end

Comment: Its simple: looks into empty string. doesnt matter if its one or two spaces. try it this way 'value  ' and check result set

Comment: *If* SQL Server would adhere to Standard SQL it would be really simple:`where col like ' '`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, it ignores trailing spaces in comparisons.

You can try to append a delimiting character.

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM mytable
WHERE col + 'X' = ' X';
```

Comment: Technically the standard requires the shorter string be padded with spaces until it has the same length as the longer string. In practice though, I've never found a situation where that would produce a different outcome than trimming/ignoring the trailing spaces.

Comment: Unfortunately, this precludes the use of indexes.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Could that be solved with `WHERE col = ' ' AND col+'X' = ' X'`? The first part is indexed, then it applies the refinement.

Comment: @barmar . . . I would go with `col = ' ' and len(col) = 1`.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever An off the cuff first thought with no experimentation:  Maybe [unicode spaces](http://jkorpela.fi/chars/spaces.html)?

Answer (score 3):

You can combine `DATALENGTH` clause with your query:

```
   select COUNT(*)
   from mytable
   where col = ' '
   and DATALENGTH(col) = 1
```

Answer (score 3):

The [link](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/10510/behavior-of-varchar-with-spaces-at-the-end) posted by Ivan Starostin in the comments of the OP provides a good explanation and I think it deserves a full answer instead of just a comment.

To summarize, try using LIKE instead of equality:

```
select COUNT(*)
from mytable
where col LIKE ' ' -- one space
```

And you can also use DATALENGTH to calculate how many bytes are in the field to double-check field length:

```
select col, DATALENGTH(col)
from mytable;
```

Please note that DATALENGTH will return a different value if col is a VARCHAR vs NVARCHAR. VARCHAR stores each character as 1 byte where NVARCHAR stores each character as 2 bytes since NVARCHAR is stored in Unicode.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the single space with a single character (for exampe `§`) and then put this character in your `where` condition:

```
declare @tmp table(col varchar(50))

insert into @tmp values
(' '),
('  '),
('   ')

select COUNT(*) as one_space_count
from @tmp
where replace(col,' ','§')='§'

select COUNT(*) as two_space_count
from @tmp
where replace(col,' ','§')='§§'

select COUNT(*) as three_space_count
from @tmp
where replace(col,' ','§')='§§§'
```

Results:

[image]